# Making instance variable static

Tags: java

I met such a Java problem about making instance variables static:

```
public class Student {
 private static String name;

 public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }  
}
```

and test:

```
public void testBadStatic() {
  Student studentA = new Student("a");
  assertEquals("a", studentA.getName());
  Student studentB = new Student("b");
  assertEquals("b", studentB.getName());
  assertEquals("a", studentA.getName());
```

I think the second assertEquals will fail, since the name variable is static, so it already been assigned "a". However, the correct output should be true for the second assertion and false for the last assertion. Could anybody help me understand this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this test to pass while still having the `name` field `static`?

Comment: I think you are confusing `static` and `final`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> public Student(String name) {

This is your constructor. Whenever you create an instance of this class, this "method" is called. However, static variables belong to the class. Thus, setting the static String name to a value changes it for all existing instances.

Comment: constructor is constructor NOT a method

Comment: You are right - constructors are somewhat different from methods. For example, they don't have an explicit return type.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused between `final` and `static` variables.

**Final** (but not static) variables are tied to instances, and can get values in the constructor, or through static initialization.

**Static** variables are tied to classes, so they share the same value across one JVM instance for all instances of the given class.

**Final static** variables offer the most restricted of the two: it is effectivelz a constant: cannot be changed, and is the same for all instances of the given class.

Conclusion: the

```
this.name = name;
```

statement updates a value, that is tied to the class, rather than the indvidual instances, so after such a call, each instance will "see" that same value - the result of the last assignment operation.

Answer (score 2):

The second assert won't fail, because this line:

```
Student studentB = new Student("b");
```

Will change the `name` variable for *all* instances.

So when the second assert comes around, `Student.name` *is* `"b"`.  (Note that this is the `Student` class I'm referencing here).

The third assert will indeed fail, because the `name` for all instances (both `studentA` and `studentB` are now `"b"`.

In other words:

```
Student studentA = new Student("a");
  // studentA.name = "a"
assertEquals("a", studentA.getName());    // This passes
Student studentB = new Student("b");
  // studentB.name = "b"
  // studentA.name = "b"
assertEquals("b", studentB.getName());    // This passes
assertEquals("a", studentA.getName());    // This fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
public class Student {
    private static String name;

    public Student(String name) {
        Studen.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Student.name;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is not "static" in the sense of "unchanging" - it means that all instances share the same variable, so the second constructor call replaced the value of the static variable with "b".

Answer (score 0):

The second assertion will pass you assign "b" to your static variable in constructor. This is also why the third assertion will fail (expected "a", found "b").